# WebSphere 8.5 - Linux OS problems in simple log output

Tags: java, linux, websphere

I am experiencing a strange behavior on Linux with Websphere 8.5.  My application is a basic FE Web with Struts 1-1 which calls a legacy system written in COBOL.
The call is made via CTG, essentially by sending a String to the CICS server and then parsing back the response.
The application runs correctly in test environment but not in production.
The problem is that when composing the string with the data to pass via CTG I see all strange characters, something like this:

> *10-07-2014 11:15:44 -DEBUG- Utility.aggiungiBlank str: 05034                               55555
>
>   er/tivoli/tam/PolicyDirector
>
>   /org/isoa/appkyc/properties/ErrorResources_it.  9
>   org/isoa/appkyc/properties/ErrorResources_it.propertiesp.n??  ?? 
>   rofiles/AppSrv01/properties/org/o
>
>   kyc/properties/ErrorResources_it.properties               64/lib/. 
>   ????  )     ??‚ org/isoa/appkyc  9
>   org/isoa/appkyc/properties/ErrorResources_it
>
>   Server/java_1.7_64/li                 ebSphere/AppServer/lib/..h??
>
>   t.properties.h??9 org/isoa/appkyc/*

I am really confused, it seems to be related to the struts messages, which are correctly defined with just one file named ErrorResources.properties. So if it does not find the correct locale it should consider the default file.

Consider that the line of code which produces this strange output is just a simple java method which uses internally a String buffer to generate the calling string.

Any ideas of what could be the problem?

Comment: Hi, could you post some code? Where are you seeing all the strange data? SystemOut.log, or on the CICS Transaction Gateway?

Comment: Hi that strange log was in the SystemOut.log.  Than it suddenly disappeared when they downgraded the JVM from 1.7 to 1.6. Really can't explain it...